# Low side and High side switches

Tags: switches

Why do we go for a Low side / High Side Switch ? Why do I find more of Low side switches than High Side in Automobile electronics ?

Comment: cost - amp for amp n channel devices are cheaper than p channel types

Answer (score 3):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFl6sn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. (a) NPN open collector switch. (b) A failed attempt to make a PNP version.*

The low side switch is very simple as shown in Figure 1a. The low-voltage logic just has to feed sufficient current into the NPN transistor to turn it fully on.

There is a temptation to think that we could do the same trick with an PNP transistor as shown in Figure 1b. The problem is that the emitter-base junction is always forward biased. This will apply the 12 V to the chip output and destroy it or, if there are protection diodes on the output, the current will flow through the protection diodes into the micro-controller supply (shown as 5 V in this case). The effect of this current flow is to turn on Q3 and the load can not be switched off.

There are ways around the problem of Figure 1b but they are all more complex.

Answer (score 1):

what the guys said is totally correct . but your initial statment is not accurate "Why do I find more of Low side switches than High Side in Automobile electronics ?"

Proof in this document: [HIGH SIDE SWITCH Stmicroelectronics](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/5a/5e/5e/69/af/46/4e/42/CD00003919.pdf/files/CD00003919.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003919.pdf)

I will QUOTE :

> Almost  every  electronic  switch  used  in  a
>   modern  automobile  application  is  a  high
>   side  switch.      This  configuration  is
>   preferred  for  automotive  use  because:
>   a) - This configuration protects the load
>   from continuous operation and resulting
>   failure,    if  there  is  a  short  circuit    to  the
>   ground. Since the body of a car is metal
>   and  95%  of  the  total  car  is  ground,  the
>   short  to  ground  is  much  more  common
>   than  short  to  VCC
>   b)  -  High  Side  Drivers  cause  less
>   problems  with  electro-chemical
>   corrosion.      It  is  of  primary  importance
>   in  automotive  systems  because  the
>   electrical components are in an adverse
>   environment,  specifically  adverse
>   temperatures  and  humidity  and  the
>   presence  of  salt.  For  this  reason  the
>   series  switch  is  connected  between  the
>   load  and  the  positive  power  source.
>   Therefore    when    the  electrical component  is  not  powered  (that  is  for
>   the  greatest  part  of  the  lifetime  of  the
>   car)  it  is  at  the  lowest  potential  and
>   electrochemical corrosion does not take
>   place.

Comment: Thank you "ElectronS". that was useful. Now I have a new question :) that if a Low side switch can detect a short to GND, and if a High side switch can detect a short to BAT. and How ? I know how a short to BAT at Low side and short to GND at a high side can be detected.

Comment: did you think before asking the question ??? why would you need to detect short to GND on high side driver ?? the load in this case is connected between GND and the driver . how can the load be shorted to ground if it is connected to ground !!!!  and the same goes for the low side driver but vis versa.

Answer (score 0):

As [Jim pointed out](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/245603/low-side-and-high-side-switches#comment539532_245603), cost is a driving factor, because n-channel MOSFETs are easier to produce with low on-resistance and high current capabilities.

Other than that, ease of construction: With a single MOSFET low-side, you can switch a (basically) unlimited voltage, because the voltage that decides about whether the device is on or off is the Gate-Drain voltage; Let drain sit on Ground, then you see that you can use a typical logical level 0 or 1 to switch the device on or off.

If you put the switch on the high side, you inevitably need to have some circuitry that translates between the logic levels, which are typically much closer to ground than to the voltages of the high side.